# How can i move a Horizontal Stack upwards in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to Swift UI a small help will be appreciated a lot.

Right now my app design looks as shown below in image

[this is image please see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y39ol.png)

the code for my app is as shown below

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(){
        ZStack {
            VStack(){
                
                HStack(){
                    Text("All Savings Bank Accounts")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .frame( alignment: .top)
                    Button("+") {
                        isSavingsFundsAlertsPresented = true
                    }.font(.title2)
                    .frame(alignment: .top)
                }
                Spacer()
                List(allBankAccountFunds){
                    aRow in TableRowSavingsAccount(Account: aRow)
                }
            }
            AlertView(isShown: $isSavingsFundsAlertsPresented, Name: $SavingAccountName, Amount: $SavingAccountAmount, title: "Add Savings Account", placeholder: "Name of Account", buttonText: "Add Account") {
                if(SavingAccountName != ""){
                    let newAccount = SavingsAccount(context: context);
                    newAccount.accountName = SavingAccountName;
                    newAccount.accountBalance = Double(SavingAccountAmount) ?? 0;
                    
                    do{
                        try context.save()
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                    //after the alert has ended closure of on Done function
            }
        }
        ZStack {
            VStack{
```

even though i included spacer() in between HStack and List, still Hstack is way low,

All i want to achieve is to somehow reduce the space between Text("All savings bank account") and top notch.

if i try to ignoreallsafeEdges() the Hstack completely disappears.

I am new to swiftUI , any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like navigation bar + title area (plus maybe default spacing).

Comment: @Asperi can you please enlighten me on how can i change the hieght or remove title area and navigation bar??

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example of how do you construct entire scene to avoid guessing.

Comment: Is this inside a NaviagtionView? You can try navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) if you have a title or hide the navigation bar,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you present this `View` inside `NavigationView`, default `NavigationBar` appears.

If you add

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

to `VStack` which below `body`, `NavigationBar` will be hidden.